# Cannot get windows phone 8.1 template in VS express 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I have both visual studio express 2012 and 2013 installed. I have run the windows phone 8.1 standalone SDK but there is no template in either IDE for the c# or VB, only for JavaScript. Anyone know what I can do? I am trying to take some online courses to teach myself how to make windows phone apps but they all say start with the windows phone template for c#, and I really want to program in VB which I have experience in already.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio Express for you have installed? You need the "for Windows" version, not the "Web" or "For Windows Desktop". Download can be found here: https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/profile/review?download=true&family=VisualStudioExpressWindows&release=VisualStudio2013Upd4&type=web

Comment: @jessehouwing  Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows

Comment: forget the Express edition. Use the free Community Edition of VS2013 which has the Pro features.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Ok, ill try it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thank you, that worked. Had to repair the install for the community edition.